# Angular's ngOnInit and the Timing of Records Being Returned via an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using an observable to track an array of records in my Angular 2 app.

Because the results of this observable are being stored in "records", I am using "records" to iterate over and print to my view with an *ngFor="let record of records". This is all working as expected.

However, I'm trying to figure out why if I have a separate function that console logs the length of the array of records, I get a "0" returned.

Right now I am doing all of this within Angular's ngOnInit life cycle hook. So it looks like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getAllClients()
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);

    this.isActive();
}
```

Below the OnInit I am setting up my method for "isActive" like this:

```
isActive() {
    console.log('The total number of active records is ' + this.records.length);
}
```

I'm guessing the issue is that "records" is not available at the time of the console.log during OnInit. What could I do differently to get the actual length of the array once "records" has been returned?

Comment: Correct. There is no guarantee the `getAllClients()` call will finish before `this.isActive()` is reached. To access/operate on that data, you would need to include it in the success parameter of `.subscribe()`

Comment: The challenge is, because I am returning a get request from the server, I can't tack on a console.log, because it's unreachable code at that point. So how would one "include it in the success parameter of .subscribe()"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the data in the success parameter of `.subscribe()` you can still use an anonymous function, you just need to modify how it is written:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getAllClients()
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => { // note the curly braces
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            this.isActive();
        },
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
}
```

Adding the curly braces allows for multi-line anonymous methods.

Comment: Excellent. Much appreciated!

Comment: You can also set the console.log to the `OnCompleted` function, which will fire just after the Success Function